# How to create ACL using DFC code

Tags: documentum-dfc

**Please  post the code sample  to create ACl (Access control list) using DFC code   in Documentum.**

Thanks,
Asfaque

Answer (score 0):

Try this dear Friend

1. Main class

   ```
   public class Main {

       static LoginSession obj = null;
       static IDfSession idfSession = null;

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           String userName = "userName";
           String password = "password";
           String docbaseName = "repository";

           try {
               obj = new LoginSession();
               idfSession = obj.getDfSession(userName, password, docbaseName);         

               // Create ACL
               CreateACL createACL = new CreateACL();
               createACL.createACL(idfSession);        


           } finally {
               if (idfSession != null) {
                   obj.getiDfSessionManager().release(idfSession);
                   System.out.println("Session released");
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. LoginSession

   ```
   public class LoginSession {
   private IDfSessionManager iDfSessionManager = null;
   private IDfSession idfsession = null;

   public IDfSessionManager getiDfSessionManager() {
       return iDfSessionManager;
   }

   public void setiDfSessionManager(IDfSessionManager iDfSessionManager) {
       this.iDfSessionManager = iDfSessionManager;
   }

   public IDfSession getIdfsession() {
       return idfsession;
   }

   public void setIdfsession(IDfSession idfsession) {
       this.idfsession = idfsession;
   }

   public IDfSession getDfSession(String userName, String password, String docbaseName) throws Exception {
       IDfLoginInfo loginInfo = new DfLoginInfo();
       loginInfo.setUser(userName);
       loginInfo.setPassword(password);
       IDfClient client = new DfClient();

       iDfSessionManager = client.newSessionManager();
       iDfSessionManager.setIdentity(docbaseName, loginInfo);

       idfsession = iDfSessionManager.getSession(docbaseName);

       if (idfsession != null)
       System.out.println("Session created successfully");
       return idfsession;
   }

   }
   ```
3. ACL Class

   ```
   public class CreateACL {
       String name = "bhuwan1_acl";
       String description = "bhuwan_acl_descrip";

       public void createACL(IDfSession idfSession) throws DfException {
           IDfACL acl = (IDfACL) idfSession.newObject("dm_acl");
           if (acl != null) {
               acl.setObjectName(name);
               acl.setDescription(description);
               acl.save();
           }

           IDfPermit permit = new DfPermit();
           if (permit != null) {
               permit.setAccessorName("Bhuwan User");
               permit.setPermitType(IDfPermit.DF_ACCESS_PERMIT);
               permit.setPermitValue(IDfACL.DF_PERMIT_READ_STR);
               acl.grantPermit(permit);
               acl.save();
           }
           System.out.println("ACL created");
       }
   }
   ```